# Probability of tossing a coin 4 times and getting a tie and winning?

Tags: probability

Me and friend flip a coin 4 times, whoever gets most heads wins. Each coin flip is independent of each other and the coins are fair. (So the probability of a flip is 1/2)

Show that the probability of a tie (we get the same number of heads) is the same as getting exactly 4 heads and 4 tails on 8 coin flips. Use this answer to calculate the probability of someone winning (getting more heads than the other person).

Also, If I toss the coin 5 times, while my friend only tosses hers 4 times, calculate the probability that I will get strictly more heads than my friend.

---

So the possible outcomes for the first question is ((HHHH),(HHHH)),((HTHH)(HTHH), ((HHTH),(HHTH)), ((HHHT),(HHHT)),..., ((TTTT),(TTTT)). Am I thinking of this right? So I am trying to prove that the probaility of the above outcomes is equal to the probability of getting (HHHHHHHH)? Still not sure how to figure out the second and third question.

Comment: You cannot answer like that. Start computing player A gets 4 heads independently , player B the same, and then player A and player B. Do the same with 3 , 2 , 1 and 0 heads, alone and both. And then, you wil get elements to answer.

Comment: You can prove that all ties (as well as 4 heads and 4 tails, which is essentially the same thing as a tie, where you play with 1 coin) have a 1/2 probability with induction. For the second and third question, you should do a binomial distribution.

Comment: @The monkey - I'm missing what the link is between the two probabilities, other than they both work out at the same value - having worked that out, the chance of a winner is surely 1 - p, the chance of an individual winner (1 - p) / 2 - I'd tackle the last one by working out p(1),p(2) ... for each of them, then I can work out p(n>m and m) for each value of m

Comment: 'A friend and I' you wouldn't say 'me flip a coin 4 times' - did a prof write it?  Tell him off.

Comment: @Andrew yup, ill also tell him i got the answers from stackexchange lol

Answer (score 1):

> "Show that the probability of a tie (we get the same number of heads) is the same as getting exactly 4 heads and 4 tails on 8 coin flips."

Let $H,T$ denote the number of heads and tails repectively flipped
by you in $4$ flips .

Let $H',T'$ denote the number of heads and tails respectively flipped
by your friend in $4$ flips.

Then the probability of a tie is $\Pr\left(H=H'\right)$.

But $T'$has the same distribution as $H'$ and there is independence, so we observe:

$\Pr\left(H=H'\right)=\Pr\left(H=T'\right)=\Pr\left(H=4-H'\right)=\Pr\left(H+H'=4\right)$

The last probability can be recognized as the probability of $4$
heads by $8$ flips (the flips of you and your friend taken together).

> "Use this answer to calculate the probability of someone winning (getting more heads than the other person)."

Now we have:

- $\Pr\left(\text{tie}\right)=\Pr\left(H+H'=4\right)=2^{-8}\binom{8}{4}$.
- $1=\Pr\left(\text{you win}\right)+\Pr\left(\text{tie}\right)+\Pr\left(\text{friend wins}\right)$
- $\Pr\left(\text{you win}\right)=\Pr\left(\text{friend wins}\right)$

leading to: $$\Pr\left(\text{you win}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-2^{-8}\binom{8}{4}\right)$$

> "Also, If I toss the coin 5 times, while my friend only tosses hers 4 times, calculate the probability that I will get strictly more heads than my friend."

If you toss $5$ times then think of it as a match1 as described above that is followed by an extra toss of you, and call the whole thing match2.

Now apply that:

$$\Pr\left(\text{you win match2}\right)=$$$$\Pr\left(\text{you win match1}\right)+\Pr\left(\text{match1 ends in a tie}\wedge\text{extra toss is a head}\right)=\Pr\left(\text{you win match1}\right)+\Pr\left(\text{match1 ends in a tie}\right)\Pr\left(\text{extra toss is a head}\right)=$$$$\frac{1}{2}\left(1-2^{-8}\binom{8}{4}\right)+2^{-8}\binom{8}{4}\times\frac12=\frac12$$

There is another (more elegant) route to this result.

Let $H,T$ denote the number of heads and tails repectively flipped
by you in $5$ flips .

Let $H',T'$ denote the number of heads and tails respectively flipped
by your friend in $4$ flips.

The probability of winning for you is $\Pr(H>H')$ and just as above we find:

$\Pr\left(H>H'\right)=\Pr\left(H>T'\right)=\Pr\left(H>4-H'\right)=\Pr\left(H+H'>4\right)$

The RHS is the probability that by $9$ flips there are more heads than tails. Symmetry then tells us that this equals $\frac12$.

Comment: How does Pr(match1 ends in a tie∧extra toss is a head) = Pr(extra toss is a head)Pr(extra toss is a head) ? Is this because the events are independent?

Comment: And does Pr(extra toss is a head) just equal 1/2? So in general, Pr(you win match2) = winning match 1 multiplied by 1/4?

Comment: Sorry, but the last line in my answer was not correct (caused by copying, pasting and no checking). I have repaired now. On your comments: yes, because the events are independent, and yes P(extra toss is head)=1/2.

Comment: What you say about "multiplied by 1/4" is unclear to me.